# How to perform UPSERT or MERGE operation in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to update and insert records to old Dataframe using unique column "ID" using Apache Spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update Dataframe, you can perform "left_anti" join on unique columns and then UNION it with Dataframe which contains new records

```
def refreshUnion(oldDS: Dataset[_], newDS: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String]): Dataset[_] = {
    val filteredNewDS = selectAndCastColumns(newDS, oldDS)
    oldDS.join(
      filteredNewDS,
      usingColumns,
      "left_anti")
      .select(oldDS.columns.map(columnName => col(columnName)): _*)
      .union(filteredNewDS.toDF)
  }

  def selectAndCastColumns(ds: Dataset[_], refDS: Dataset[_]): Dataset[_] = {
    val columns = ds.columns.toSet
    ds.select(refDS.columns.map(c => {
      if (!columns.contains(c)) {
        lit(null).cast(refDS.schema(c).dataType) as c
      } else {
        ds(c).cast(refDS.schema(c).dataType) as c
      }
    }): _*)
  }

val df = refreshUnion(oldDS, newDS, Seq("ID"))
```

Comment: just trying to understand what selectandCastcolumns function do..it would be good if you can through bit light on this.

Comment: selectandCastcolumns tries to rearrange, cast columns and populate miss column with null values as per refDS

Answer (score 0):

Spark Dataframes are immutable structure. Therefore, you can't do any update based on the ID.

The way to update dataframe is to merge the older dataframe and the newer dataframe and save the merged dataframe on HDFS. To update the older ID you would require some de-duplication key (Timestamp may be).

I am adding the sample code for this in scala. You need to call the `merge` function with the uniqueId and the timestamp column name. Timestamp should be in Long.

```
case class DedupableDF(unique_id: String, ts: Long);

def merge(snapshot: DataFrame)(
      delta: DataFrame)(uniqueId: String, timeStampStr: String): DataFrame = {
    val mergedDf = snapshot.union(delta)
    return dedupeData(mergedDf)(uniqueId, timeStampStr)

  }

def dedupeData(dataFrameToDedupe: DataFrame)(
      uniqueId: String,
      timeStampStr: String): DataFrame = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    def removeDuplicates(
        duplicatedDataFrame: DataFrame): Dataset[DedupableDF] = {
      val dedupableDF = duplicatedDataFrame.map(a =>
        DedupableDF(a(0).asInstanceOf[String], a(1).asInstanceOf[Long]))
      val mappedPairRdd =
        dedupableDF.map(row ⇒ (row.unique_id, (row.unique_id, row.ts))).rdd;
      val reduceByKeyRDD = mappedPairRdd
        .reduceByKey((row1, row2) ⇒ {
          if (row1._2 > row2._2) {
            row1
          } else {
            row2
          }
        })
        .values;
      val ds = reduceByKeyRDD.toDF.map(a =>
        DedupableDF(a(0).asInstanceOf[String], a(1).asInstanceOf[Long]))
      return ds;
    }

    /** get distinct unique_id, timestamp combinations **/
    val filteredData =
      dataFrameToDedupe.select(uniqueId, timeStampStr).distinct

    val dedupedData = removeDuplicates(filteredData)

    dataFrameToDedupe.createOrReplaceTempView("duplicatedDataFrame");
    dedupedData.createOrReplaceTempView("dedupedDataFrame");

    val dedupedDataFrame =
      sqlContext.sql(s""" select distinct duplicatedDataFrame.*
                  from duplicatedDataFrame
                  join dedupedDataFrame on
                  (duplicatedDataFrame.${uniqueId} = dedupedDataFrame.unique_id
                  and duplicatedDataFrame.${timeStampStr} = dedupedDataFrame.ts)""")
    return dedupedDataFrame
  }
```